# Summary Data table

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, datatable, report

I have built a report on a daily collection and a summary of the collection via `paymentType` is required. I have to utilize a data table to create the daily collection report because there is also a date range picker. The summary will be linked in the button as well. I'm wondering how to create this summary. Can someone help me to do so?

Comment: With respect @gayu96 - This isn't a `Do my work for me site - it's a Q&A site. If you were to show `some` willing, people would be happy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"John", "A", 1.23});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Harry", "B", 4.56 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Dick", "C", 7.89 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "B", 6.54 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Pat", "D", 1.23 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Dana", "A", 8.76 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Rob", "C", 9.65 });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Type")).ToList();

            DataTable summary = new DataTable();
            summary.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            summary.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = summary.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Type"] = group.Key;
                newRow["Amount"] = group.Select(x => x.Field<decimal>("Amount")).Sum();
            }
```